# Не отображается картинка в Rails приложении

Tags: html5, ruby-on-rails, ruby, изображения

Показывает вот такую ошибку

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Zet#index
Showing C:/Sites/zet/app/views/zet/index.html.erb where line #8 raised:

The asset "example_image.png" is not present in the asset pipeline.
Extracted source (around line #8):
6
7
8
9
10
11

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Тестовая программа на <%=image_tag("example_image.png", alt: "Example Image")%> </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Фотография размещена в каталоге public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переложите картинку в `app/assets/images` и будет вам счастье. В проде рельсы скомпилят ассеты и положат всё в public. И почитайте внимательно про работу [asset pipeline](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)